# Route to dask worker debug pages

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

The docs say:

```
Debug Worker pages for each worker at http://worker-address:8789. 
These pages have detailed diagnostic information about the worker.
Like the diagnostic scheduler pages they are of more utility to
developers or to people looking to understand the performance of
their underlying cluster. If port 8789 is unavailable (for example 
it is in use by another worker) then a random port is chosen. A list
of all ports can be obtained from looking at the service ports for
each worker in the result of calling client.scheduler_info()
```

I can see the `bokeh` service (which is, I presume, what I'm looking for) in `scheduler_info()`.  However, if I hit that port for a LocalCluster I just get a `404`.  This suggests to me that it should have a route attached, but what is it?

Further, it looks like the KubeCluster doesn't have a `bokeh` service at all.  Should I be able to get a worker status page there at all, or is it just not implemented for KubeCluster?

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  I found it:

https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/bokeh/worker.py#L663

Specifically, `/main` (and the other routes there).